# smartsheet API Update PICKLIST column error

Tags: javascript, smartsheet-api-2.0

I am getting an error using the Smartsheet API to update a row in a smartsheet document.  Previously this has been working, so I think something may have changed recently in the smartsheet api that is causing this error, but I couldn't find any smartsheet documentation to support that.  The error is:
`Error Code: 1235 - Value is not supported for this column type. Use objectValue instead. Ref ID: <refIdHere>`

According to the Smartsheet API documentation, the objectValue is used for MULTI_PICKLIST.  I am not using any MULTI_PICKLIST in my smartsheet, just using a PICKLIST, DATE, CHECKBOX, TEXT_NUMBER.

What is the correct format to send to PUT https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/sheetid/rows ?
Here is the format that I have been using, which was working until a few weeks ago.  It didn't matter if the columns were PICKLIST, DATE, CHECKBOX or TEXT_NUMBER, this format was working.  Now it is failing when updating a PICKLIST column.  Also, what does the RefId reference?

````
    "id": "<sheetId>",
    "cells": [{
        "columnId": 4714233383413635,
        "value": 123456
    }, {
        "columnId": 5840133290256265,
        "value": "Africa"
    }, {
        "columnId": 5277183336834945,
        "value": "French"
    }, {
        "columnId": 8654883057362825,
        "value": "2020-09-04"
    }]
}]```
````

Comment: Is there any column of type MultiContactList, Predecessor, or Allocation ?

Answer (score 0):

There have been no changes to the API that would break behavior. It is possible the column type in your sheet was changed? I would double check the types of your columns to be sure.

`value` is a legacy format that still exists to preserve backwards compatibility with existing systems. It is strongly recommended you use `objectValue`, which for strings and numbers, behaves exactly the same way as `value`.

For example:

```
"objectValue": 123456
```

Answer (score 0):

add `"strict": false` to cell:

```
"cells": [{
  "columnId": 4714233383413635,
  "value": 123456,
  "strict": false
}
```